# axios is not saving an Array in to MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to pass an `array` of `subjects` to `MongoDB` with the help of `axios` with other data.

Problem is it is (`axios`) is not saving `subject array` to the `MongoDB`

Here is my `AddCourse.jx`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axio from 'axios';

export default class AddCourse extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            colorChange: true,
            coloChangeTwo: true,
            courseName: '',
            courseCode: '',
            passMarks: '',
            lectureInCharge: '',
            subjects: []

        };

    }

    onClick(){
        this.setState({
            colorChange: !this.state.colorChange
        });

        if(this.state.colorChange){

            this.state.subjects.push('1');

        }else{
            var search_term = '1';
            for(var i = this.state.subjects.length-1; i>=0; i--){
                if(this.state.subjects[i] === search_term){
                    this.state.subjects.splice(i, 1);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    onClick2(){
        this.setState({
            coloChangeTwo: !this.state.coloChangeTwo
        });
        if(this.state.coloChangeTwo){

           this.state.subjects.push('2');

        }else{
            var search_term = '2';
            for(var i = this.state.subjects.length-1; i>=0; i--){
                if(this.state.subjects[i] === search_term){
                    this.state.subjects.splice(i, 1);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    onSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        //new course object
        const newCourse = {
            courseName: this.state.courseName,
            courseCode: this.state.courseCode,
            passMarks: this.state.passMarks,
            lectureInCharge: this.state.lectureInCharge,
            subjects: this.state.subjects
        };
        // console.log(this.state.subjects);
        // console.log(newCourse);

        axio.post('http://localhost:4000/course/add', newCourse)
            .then((res) => {
                console.log('Course ' + res + ' Added!');
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
        });

        this.setState({
            colorChange: true,
            coloChangeTwo: true,
            courseName: '',
            courseCode: '',
            passMarks: '',
            lectureInCharge: '',
            subjects: []
        });

    }

    onChangeCourseName(e){
        this.setState({
            courseName: e.target.value
        });
    }
    onChangeCourseCode(e){
        this.setState({
            courseCode: e.target.value
        });
    }
    onChangePassMarks(e){
        this.setState({
            passMarks: e.target.value
        });
    }
    onChangeLectureInCharge(e){
        this.setState({
            lectureInCharge: e.target.value
        });
    }

    render() {

        let beforeClickingButton = 'btn btn-warning';
        let afterClickingButton = 'btn btn-secondary';
        let subjectButtonClass1 = this.state.colorChange ? beforeClickingButton : afterClickingButton;
        let subjectButtonClass2 = this.state.coloChangeTwo ? beforeClickingButton : afterClickingButton;

        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Add Course</h1>
                <br />

                <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit.bind(this)}>
                    <div className="container">

                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label>Course Name:</label>
                            <input
                                value={this.state.courseName}
                                onChange={this.onChangeCourseName.bind(this)}
                                type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Course Name" />
                        </div>

                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label>Course Code:</label>
                            <input
                                value={this.state.courseCode}
                                onChange={this.onChangeCourseCode.bind(this)}
                                type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Course Code" />
                        </div>

                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label>Pass Mark</label>
                            <input
                                value={this.state.passMarks}
                                onChange={this.onChangePassMarks.bind(this)}
                                type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Pass Mark"/>
                        </div>

                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label>Lecture In Charge:</label>
                            <input
                                value={this.state.lectureInCharge}
                                onChange={this.onChangeLectureInCharge.bind(this)}
                                type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Lecture in Charge"/>
                        </div>

                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label>Subjects: Select Subjects from below... (Green = Not Selected/Grey = Selected)</label>
                            <div className="container">
                                <div className="row text-center">
                                    <div className="col-6">
                                        <button
                                            onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}
                                            className={subjectButtonClass1}
                                            type="button" >Computer Architecture</button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="col-6">
                                        <button
                                            onClick={this.onClick2.bind(this)}
                                            className={subjectButtonClass2}
                                            type="button">Computer Networking</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success btn-lg">Save Course</button>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

And here is my `server.js` in node environment

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const CourseDB = require('./course-dbmodel');

const PORT = 4000;

const app = express();
const router = express.Router();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use('/course', router);

mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/course', {useNewUrlParser: true});
const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once('open', () => {
    console.log('MongoDB connected through the port 27017');
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log('Listening to port 4000');
});

//add course
//http://localhost:4000/course/add
router.route('/add').post((req, res) => {
    let courseDb = new CourseDB(req.body);
    courseDb.save().then(course => {
        res.status(200).send('Added!');
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
});

//get all courses
router.route('/all').get((req, res) => {
    CourseDB.find((err, course) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        res.status(200).send(course);
    });
});

//get books by course name
router.route('/:courseName').get((req, res) => {
    let courseName = req.params.courseName;
    CourseDB.find({subject: {$regex: `${courseName}`}},(err, subjects) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        res.status(200).send(subjects);
    })


});
```

And here is the `mongoose database schema` I use to store value to the `MongoDB`

```
const mongoose= require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let CourseDb = new Schema({
    courseName: {type: String},
    courseCode: {type: String},
    passMarks: {type: Number},
    lectureInCharge: {type: String},
    subject: [{type: String}]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('CourseDb', CourseDb, 'CourseDb');
```

Can someone please tell me what wrong did I do?

A screen shot of my data in database

[image: Screenshot]

And this is when I `consolo.log()` the `newCourse` object

[image]

Comment: can you please try putting a `console.log` on `/add` route and also before axios post in order to check `subject` value.

Comment: Yes, will upload a screenshot

Comment: Done!Check my updated answer @niccord

Comment: ok, what about server logs?

Comment: What do you mean? Sorry?

Comment: you probably have a shell where you started your server locally on your machine. If you add `console.log(courseDb )` on `server.js` inside the `add` route function, and then click the button from your browser, do you see anything in the shell? (remember to restart the server)

Comment: change `subject` to `subjects` looks like you forgot `s` in the server-end.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your schema:

replace

```
subject: [{type: String}]
```

with

```
subject: [String]
```

I would write this as a comment, but I don't have commenting powers!

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#arrays